# Making a Ruby block return an array?

Tags: ruby, block, dsl

I've made a small DSL-like program for adding drinks to an array. It's a pretty basic example for using `instance_eval` and `&block` to create a quick program.

Here's the program:

```
class Drinks
  def initialize(&block) # Initialize drinks
    @drinks = []
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def drink(d)
    @drinks << d
  end # Add drink

  def all_drinks
    puts @drinks
  end

end

add_drinks = Drinks.new do
  drink "water"
  drink "soda"
  drink "juice"
end

add_drinks.all_drinks
```

The plan is to make `add_drinks` auto-return itself so you don't have to use `add_drinks.all_drinks`. Would this be possible? Thanks.

Comment: "auto-return itself"? But that's not what you want, you want the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inherit Drinks from Array, so you can work with new instance as with array

```
class Drinks < Array
  def initialize(&block) # Initialize drinks
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def drink(d)
    self << d
  end # Add drink
end

add_drinks = Drinks.new do
  drink "water"
  drink "soda"
  drink "juice"
end

add_drinks  #  => ["water", "soda", "juice"]
```

Comment: I realise this is off topic but I'd just like to say that this helped me fix a problem and make my code less verbose + simpler so thanks, I don't know why but I didn't consider doing the `instance_eval` inside of the initializer rather then outside of it in the constructor so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rethink what the object is and how it behaves. Maybe do it like this:

```
class Drinks
  def initialize(&block)
    @drinks = []
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def add(d)
    @drinks << d
  end

  def show
    puts @drinks
  end
end

drinks = Drinks.new do
  add "water"
  add "soda"
  add "juice"
end

drinks.show
```